# Binomial probability problem - possible fault in workbook

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have the following problem:

> The proportion of adults living in a small town who are college graduates is estimated to be $p = 0.6$. To test this hypothesis, a
>   random sample of $15$ adults is selected. If the number of college
>   graduates in the sample is anywhere from $6$ to $12$, we shall not reject
>   the null hypothesis that $p = 0.6$; otherwise, we shall conclude that $p= 0.6$?Besides, Evaluate $α$ assuming that $p = 0.6$. Use the binomial
>   distribution.

Now, the solution for this part of the exercise is as follows:

$$ α = P(X≤5) + P(X≥13) = 0.0338 + (1-0.9948) = 0.0390 $$

Now, I know that $P(X≥13)$ is calculated as $ 1-P(X≤12) $, but from my probability table (and any online calculator) I found that$ P(X≤12)$ is $0.9729$ and not $0.9948$.

Can anyone help, this has been bugging me since yesterday and I'm just wondering if it is an error in the workbook I have been provided with.

Comment: Indeed I get
$$
P(X\leq 12) = \sum_{k=0}^{12} {15 \choose k} 0.6^k 0.4^{15-k} \approx 0.972~886
$$
which is the same that you obtained. Weird ... If you switch $13$ in the place of $12$, you get the book's result! Maybe there, they made a typo.

Comment: @MattiP. noticed something weird. If I go here https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx 
and plug in the values p=0.6, n=15, x=13, P(X < 13) is indeed 0.9728 but P(X ≤ 13) is 0.9948. 

Is it possible that they just calculated the wrong probability (by mistake)? 

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's it, they made a mistake.